# The automorphism group of a fixed field

Tags: galois-theory

Let $E$ be a Galois extension of $F$ with Galois group $G$, and let $L$ be the fixed field of a subgroup $H$ of $G$. Show that the automorphism group of $L/F$ is $N/H$ where $N$ is the normalizer of $H$ in $G$.

Help me a hint to prove it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We wish to show that, given any $ \sigma \in G $ , $\sigma(L)$ has a corresponding subgroup $\sigma H \sigma^{-1}$

Let $\alpha\in H$ and $x\in E$. We have $\sigma \alpha \sigma^{-1}(\sigma(x))=\sigma \alpha(x)$. Thus $\sigma(x)$ is fixed by $\sigma \alpha \sigma^{-1}$ if and only if $x$ is fixed by $\alpha$. Hence, the fixed field of $\sigma H \sigma^{-1}$ is $\sigma(L)$.